# Mesh bounces of while playing the animation

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

[image: I have applied rigid body to two of my mesh and set shape collision as the mesh for both of my objects . But when I play the animation the mesh bounces off. Can someone please clarify whats the issue. I have tried many solutions like applying the scale but none of them worked.]

[image]

I have applied Rigidbody to two of my mesh and set shape collision as the mesh for both of my objects. But when I play the animation the mesh bounces off. Can someone please clarify whats the issue. I have tried many solutions like applying the scale but none of them worked.

Comment: There should be a Bounciness setting.

Comment: Bounciness is set  to zero.